# Print whole result in interactive Scala console

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

When I type something into the Scala interactive console, the console prints the result of the statement.  If the result is too long, the console crops it (scroll right to see it):

```
scala> Array.fill[Byte](5)(0)
res1: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

scala> Array.fill[Byte](500)(0)
res2: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...

scala> "a"*5000
res3: String = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
```

How can I print the same or equivalent output, for any given object (not just a collection or array) without the cropping occurring?

Comment: A few suggestions in this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23408037/1296806

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The result is not "cropped", simply `println` is invoking `java.lang.Arrays.toString()` (since `scala.Array` is a Java array).

Specifically, `Arrays` defines a `toString` overload that works with `Object`, which calls the `toString` implementation of `java.lang.Object` on every element. Such implementation prints the reference of the object, so you end up with

```
[Lscala.Tuple2;@4de71ca9
```

which is an `Array` containing the reference `4de71ca9` to a `scala.Tuple2` object.

That has been discussed in [this ticket](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3711) years ago.

---

In the specific case of arrays, you can simply do

```
println(x.mkString("\n"))
```

or

```
x foreach println
```

or

```
println(x.deep)
```

---

### Update

To answer your last edit, you can set the maximum lenght of the strings printed by the REPL

```
scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP WHIR GYVE **
** :phase has been set to 'typer'.          **
** scala.tools.nsc._ has been imported      **
** global._, definitions._ also imported    **
** Try  :help, :vals, power.<tab>           **

scala> vals.isettings.maxPrintString = Int.MaxValue
vals.isettings.maxPrintString: Int = 2147483647
```

Comment: The Scala console is doing the cropping.  Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks - that was my original question, but I realize the question was a bit misleading.  The `println(x)` was there only to show that that answer doesn't work.

Comment: ```error: value foreach is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
       corr foreach println```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
scala> :power
Power mode enabled. :phase is at typer.
import scala.tools.nsc._, intp.global._, definitions._
Try :help or completions for vals._ and power._

scala> vals.isettings.maxPrintString
res9: Int = 800

scala> vals.isettings.maxPrintString = 10000
vals.isettings.maxPrintString: Int = 10000
```

Comment: It doesn't work ...

Answer (score 2):

try

```
x map println
```

or

```
x foreach println
```

Comment: ```error: value foreach is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
       corr foreach println```