# How to enlarge scala string output from zeppelin notebook step?

Tags: scala, apache, apache-zeppelin

Very basic issue. I am just using Zeppelin 0.8 with Scala via the Spark Interpreter - all default settings, and I can't get an output of more than around 700 characters to display.

I have looked at the tunables. They are all huge relative to the tiny sizes it it outputting for me.

```
// This creates a 4000-character string:
"4000" * 1000
```

What I get is this:

`res14: String = 4000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004000400040004...`

This is truncated way smaller than any of the maxOutput or other text limit tunings suggest. It is less than 1000 characters.

I need at least 10000 characters out. What is truncating this and how can I enlarge this limit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is truncated. It just not showing all to you on the console. This String is a const. It is there for you to use completely.

If you really hope console can show all content. Please refer to [Print whole result in interactive Scala console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26011511/print-whole-result-in-interactive-scala-console)

```sh
scala> vals.isettings.maxPrintString = Int.MaxValue
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get ```<console>:48: error: not found: value vals val $ires4 = vals.isettings.maxPrintString ^ <console>:46: error: not found: value vals vals.isettings.maxPrintString = Int.MaxValue ^```

Comment: I did understand that the string itself has all the data. The problem here is just with not displaying it all to me.

Comment: I see other stack overflow answers that suggest setting vals.isettings.maxPrintString also, but those are the interactive scala REPL. I am using Zeppelin notebooks, not the REPL. E.g., there is no ":power" command available to enable setting this vals object.

Comment: If so, would you please try adjust [interpreter_output_limit](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/setup/operation/configuration.html#zeppelin_interpreter_output_limit) ?

Comment: interpreter_output_limit is set to 102400